# window.location.pathname alternative for Next.js server side

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

My application routes look like this: `/m/{locale}/{page}`.

On client side `window.location.pathname` returns `/m/en/contacts` as expected. Now I would like to get the same pathname in `_document.tsx` (server side), but `window` is not accessible there.

I tried checking what I could do to get the path and one suggested option was to use document context under `getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext)`:

```
ctx.req?.url; // returns /contacts
ctx.asPath; // returns /contacts
```

Unfortunately it returns `/contacts` ignoring `/m/{locale}` prefix. Is there a clean way to do it?